# maven-archetype-j2ee-simple archetype logging module

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, log4j

I have a trouble understanding the `maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` archetype.

Does anybody know how to use the *logging* module inside a maven project?

Have I to configure log4j inside it? If yes, how?

Thank you,
Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `log4j` use has nothing to use with the `maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` archetype.
As you have generated your project following this archetype, I assume you hit many modules in the parent project:

```
 project
 \_ ears
 |_ ejbs
 |_ servlets
 |_ primary-sources
 |_ ...
```

This skeleton is the one a Java Enterprise application should have as it contains some EJBs which goes on the *ejbs* module and that hold the main service logic for the application along with a *primary-sources* project that should underlie additonnal sources and classes used in the application. There is also a *servlets* module which will hold `Servlet`s as the main entry for your web application.

If you want to have your logging configuration setup in place and using the apache log4j implementation just follow a simple tutorial on how to do that.

As a simple roadway I can think of is to have, the `log4j` dependency in the parent *pom.xml descriptor* so you can use the logging API in all your modules and this is straightforward and simple from developer point. But at runtime you should have a `Servlet` with an `init()` method to be called as your application starts and which **will initialize the log4j configuration** since this is not done implicitelly and needs some customization. (As you may have a *log4j.properties* holding your configuration if you don't want to go with te `BasicConfigurator`).